# 2 dimensional (graphical) topological representation of a sphere

Tags: general-topology

One page 37 of this pdf - [Surfaces](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/topology/CHAP02%20Surfaces.pdf) - it gives a graphical representation of a sphere in 2 dimensional topological format. I don't see how the image for a sphere here actually describes a sphere. Does anyone know how this image describes a sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not! They are describing the projective plane as a sphere whose antipodal (opposite) points have been identified. This is no longer a sphere.

Ah, there is indeed a picture of a sphere as an identification space. I am not able to draw pictures here, but imagine a long pointed piece of rubber, narrowing to one point at the top and to one point at the bottom. When we glue the edges together, points at the corresponding heights being attached to one another, we get a (not perfectly round) sphere with a seam on it.

Comment: There is also an image on the page for a sphere. It is on page 39 as well.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to think about it the other way round. Imagine you have a sphere and you cut from the north pole down to the south pole and then pull it apart and try to lay it flat. If the material was suitably stretchy then it would be able to lay flat on a table and would be (topologically) a disk because there are no 'holes'.

Now, run this in reverse. Start with a disk, bend it a bit and then 'zip up' the boundary to get a sphere.